# Linq filttar elementos do LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Gostaria de retornar um objeto com seus filhos, porém só queria que trouxesse os filhos que correspondessem a uma determinada condição.
ex:
tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Fornecedor
{    
    public int FornecedorID { get; set; }
    public string CnpjCpf { get; set; }
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FornecedorContato> FornecedorContato { get; set; }
}

public class FornecedorContato
{
    public int FornecedorContatoID { get; set; }
    public int FornecedorID { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}
```

No caso gostaria que dentro da lista `FornecedorContato` de `Fornecedor`, retornassem somente os elementos que estejam `Ativos`
Como poderia fazer isso em um linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei a seguinte biblioteca que já abstrai isso.

http://entityframework-plus.net/

Utilizando ela o linq ficaria da seguinte maneira.

```
var results = db
      .Fornecedor
      .IncludeFilter(f => f.FornecedorContato
                    .Where(fc => fc.Ativo == true))
```

Acredito que dessa forma fique muito mais simples.

Answer (score 3):

Você não vai conseguir filtrar o itens de uma propriedade de navegação. A única forma de aplicar um filtro nos registros filhos é fazendo a *query* separada.

Obviamente as formas abaixo consideram que esteja usando Lazy Loading.

```
var fornecedores = db.Fornecedores.Select(f => new Fornecedor
                   {
                       Id = f.Id,
                       Nome = f.Nome,
                       //Outros campos
                       FornecedorContato = f.FornecedorContato.Where(c => c.Ativo)
                   });
```

Dependendo do caso, eu preferia usar um tipo anônimo, mas precisaria de mais detalhes pra saber qual o melhor pro seu caso.

```
var fornecedores = db.Fornecedores.Select(f => new
                   {
                       Fornecedor = f,
                       Contatos = f.FornecedorContato.Where(c => c.Ativo)
                   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Para filtrar um item de uma relação utilizando `Join` deve escrever o filtro direto na relação (`Join` ou `GroupJoin` precisam de um `IEnumerable<T>` para funcionar), nesse caso especifico utilize `GroupJoin`:

```
var results = db
      .Fornecedor
      .GroupJoin(db.FornecedorContato.Where(s => s.Ativo == true),
             f => f.FornecedorID,
             c => c.FornecedorID,
             (f, c) => new { f, p })
      .Select(e => new 
             {
               Fornecedor = e.f,
               FornecedorContato = e.p
             })
      .ToList();
```

essa variável `results` deverá ser acessada da seguinte maneira:

```
results[0].Fornecedor
results[0].Contatos
```

**ou**

```
foreach(var item in results)
{
   Client a = item.Fornecedor;
   IList<FornecedorContato> p = item.FornecedorContato.ToList();
}
```

Isso são acessos simples, mas, se quiser juntar pode ser feito um `ViewModel` que represente um item com as informações ([exemplo 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881790/how-to-design-viewmodel), [exemplo2](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/), [exemplo 3](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html)).

<sub>***Observação:*** se as configurações `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;` e `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` observe que na relação dos objetos terão também uma lista, mas, essa não é filtrada igual mostrada no exemplo.</sub>